# msi error 1603 vs2008

Tags: windows-installer

I have a vs2008 with multiple .net 3.5 projects within it.  4 regular setup projects, 1 web setup project and dlls.  I want to add another web setup project, but during the installation of any added web setup projects, it fails with eventlog error 1603.  I am using IIS 7.  The current web setup project installs fine, and I can install the setup projects to the same location that the newly added web setup projects should be installing.  The inetpub folder has administrators, myusername, system, iis_iusrs, and trustedinstaller permissions.  [Edit]  Does it on both my machines, windows 7 (32 bit), windows 7 (64 bit)

[Edit]
Oh, addition to the above, I haven't modified any of the dialogs or added any bmp to the newly added web setup projects. I add them, add the project output, debug, install, and fail. I will take a look at the vs2008 dialogs with orca.exe per your suggestion after I get home.  Another thing before I leave, I was able to not add any project output to the newly added web setup project, and it install just fine. Of course, nothing was installed to the folder, but once the project output is added it fails.

[Edit]
Today's Testing and using wilogutl.exe

```
Errors Found For Log File c:\log3.txt
======================================================
5 Non-Ignored Errors
======================================================
-------------------------------------------------
Believed Error Found:

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:179]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:179]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 0, dwEventType: 103, llSequenceNumber: 678, szDescription: "".

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:180]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0.

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:180]: Unlocking Server

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:702]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.

Action ended 15:07:29: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

Proposed Solution To Error:

  A standard action or custom action caused the failure.

-------------------------------------------------

Believed Error Found:

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:179]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 0, dwEventType: 103, llSequenceNumber: 678, szDescription: "".

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:180]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0.

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:180]: Unlocking Server

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:702]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.

Action ended 15:07:29: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

Action ended 15:07:29: INSTALL. Return value 3.

Proposed Solution To Error:

  A standard action or custom action caused the failure.

-------------------------------------------------

Believed Error Found:

MSI (s) (E4:18) [15:07:29:765]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.

MSI (s) (E4:A0) [15:07:29:765]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.

MSI (c) (90:AC) [15:07:29:770]: Back from server. Return value: 1603

MSI (c) (90:AC) [15:07:29:770]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1

MSI (c) (90:AC) [15:07:29:771]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.

Action ended 15:07:29: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.

Proposed Solution To Error:

  A standard action or custom action caused the failure.

-------------------------------------------------

Believed Error Found:

MSI (c) (90:18) [15:07:29:785]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right

Action 15:07:29: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created

Action ended 15:07:31: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.

Action ended 15:07:31: INSTALL. Return value 3.

Proposed Solution To Error:

  A standard action or custom action caused the failure.

-------------------------------------------------

Believed Error Found:

MSI (c) (90:AC) [15:07:34:063]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: WebSetup. Product Version: 1.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Default Company Name. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (90:AC) [15:07:34:064]: Grabbed execution mutex.

MSI (c) (90:AC) [15:07:34:065]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist

MSI (c) (90:AC) [15:07:34:066]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603

Proposed Solution To Error:

  Fatal error during installation.

======================================================

Believed Error Found:

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:179]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:179]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 0, dwEventType: 103, llSequenceNumber: 678, szDescription: "".

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:180]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0.

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:180]: Unlocking Server

MSI (s) (E4:60) [15:07:29:702]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.

Action ended 15:07:29: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

Proposed Solution To Error:

  A standard action or custom action caused the failure.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another thread, it suggested a Filters folder was in the project.  I had to search for it since we have about 4 lvls of information in that project, but there was a Filters folder.  I renamed it, and it installed fine.

http://youarenotexpectedtounderstandthis.blogspot.com/2009/09/vsnet-2008-web-setup-project.html

Answer (score 0):

Searching for errors should be clear enough:

> DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog MaintenanceForm
>   extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels

Search in the definition for you MaintenanceForm where you position BannerBmp and check if it is too wide for the form. Either make the banner smaller or the form bigger.

**Edit1**

If this was not the root cause the next error is

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
>   package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
>   is 2826. The arguments are: UserExitForm, Line2, to the right

It looks like the dialog which should be displayed when some action has finished was wrong or did not exist.

Comment: From the looks of it, there are multiple errors messages, but for the web setup projects to fail on two different machines?  I would think there was something else to look at than whether a banner was sticking off the page.  But, I will check.  If there are any other ideas, please tell.

Comment: @Alois: please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Let's say Prog1 is a project, and Prog2 is a project.  WebSetup1 is the existing web setup project, and WebSetup2 is the newly created web setup project.  Both WebSetups work fine with Prog2, but, WebSetup2 doesn't install fine with Prog1.  Do you still suggest that the dialogs are the problem?

Comment: The wilogutil output is way too filtered. Did you enable full logging? You can do it via http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300 or install your msi from the comamnd line msiexec /i <xxx.msi> /lvx* C:\temp\msi.log. When a custom action fails there must be some log entry. The output above does not tell you which custom action did fail.